# refresh display method if field is updated x++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I have two display method fields in past workers form (termination reason (default of system), hiring status(customization)):

1. I selected worker
2. opened employment history form
3. set values of termination reason and hiring status
4. these fields should pass to grid in past worker screen but I need to refresh all browser to make fields refresh when I tried to refresh form from form refresh didn't work.

I need to refresh display method if data is updated

I tried to call (Hcmworker_ds.observe() , Hcmemployment_Ds.observe()) in display method but doesn't work also I tried formcaller.research(true) but doesn't work

Comment: Can you give some code for context?

Comment: Which version of Dynamics is being used?

Comment: D365Fo , I tried hcmWorker_ds.observe(); and tried hcmworker_ds.research(true);

Answer (score 0):

did you try ds.refresh() after ds.research()?

Actually I'd recommend use ds.reread() instead of ds.research() in this case, since there's no new records to show.